QGIS Using Fields from Template in Attribute Table
Following on from previous question, I'm looking to use existing fields in my template to populate my new attribute table when I use refactor.
Currently I'm typing what I want into the source expression each time, but as certain fields never change, I'm looking to try and automate this if possible using the template layer to copy from.
Is this possible please?

Link to previous question.
QGIS: format attribute table to match template and auto populate certain columns

So... you repeatedly run refactor fields on one single template layer, always changing certain attributes in the same way? If so, you could create a model.

Yeah exactly. How do go about making a model?

https://docs.qgis.org/3.34/en/docs/user_manual/processing/modeler.html#the-model-designer

I have researched this a bit, but to be honest it looks a bit beyond my skills at the moment.  The refactor process is at least working for me, I just can't understand how I can apply fields from my template to the refactored attribute table.

When mentioning a previous question please always provide a link to it.

Link now provided.
